# Map (apply function) Django QuerySet

Tags: django, lazy-evaluation

Is there a mechanism to map Django QuerySet items not triggering its [evaluation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)?

I am wondering about something like Python [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). A function that uses a function to apply it over the QuerySet, but keeping the lazy evaluation.

For example, using models from Django documentation [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-2), is there something like? (not real code):

```
>>> Question.objects.all().map(lambda q: q.pub_date + timedelta(hours=1))
```

which keeps the lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 5):

Just working through something like this myself. I think the best way to do it is to use a python list comprehension.

```py
[q.pub_date + timedelta(hours=1) for q in Question.objects.all()]
```

Then Django takes care of optimizing this as it would any other query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `values_list` to get any column you like:

```
Question.objects.values_list('pub_date')
```

This is simpler than anything you can cook up yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But I was wondering about something broader, not restricted to model fields.

Comment: You can use any function like `map` to iterate over a QuerySet and do what you'd like. Or you can use dictionary/list comprehensions to create data structures.

Comment: Sure, but from what i understand, that will trigger evaluation, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use annotate for this purpose, for example

```
from datetime import timedelta
from django.db.models import F, ExpressionWrapper, DateTimeField

Question.objects.annotate(
    new_pub_date=ExpressionWrapper(
       F('pub_date') + timedelta(hours=1), 
       output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
)
```

For something a little bit more complex than this example, you can use Func, Case, When